# Trouble Accessing Binary on AWS EC2 from External Source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I've installed a binary on an AWS EC2 (Linux) instance, and it's running on port `3567`. When I use `curl localhost:3567` on the EC2 instance, I get the desired output. However, when I try the same from my laptop's command line or a browser, it doesn't work.

What's puzzling is that I also have a process running on port 80, which gives the desired result from both the localhost and external sources (browser and command line).

I'd like to provide the security group's inbound traffic configuration and the output of `netstat -ntlp` to see if someone can help me figure out a solution.

**Security Group Inbound Traffic Configuration:**

[Security Group Inbound Traffic Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAYmQ.png)

**Output of `netstat -ntlp`:**

[Output of netstat -ntlp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcqP0.png)

I'm requesting the community's assistance in resolving this issue.

--

Edit: The issue persists even after binding the service to `0.0.0.0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service on port `3567` is bound to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`, so it will only accept traffic from the same server it is running on. You need to modify whatever that service is, to have it bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it does make sense. I've already bound it to 0.0.0.0, as you suggested, but the outcome remains unchanged.

Comment: One other thing to check now, would be any firewall software running on the server, such as `ufw` on Ubuntu.

Comment: If you're referring to NACL, then it's a default AWS configuration with all traffic allowed from all ports, with rule number 100.

Comment: No I'm not referencing the VPC subnet NACL, I'm referencing any firewall software running on the EC2 server operating system.

Comment: Understood. I ran `sudo tcpdump -n icmp` and observed `ICMP host unreachable`. Subsequently, I disabled the firewall using the command `sudo systemctl disable --now firewalld`, which resolved the issue. 
However, what is the recommended approach to address this situation?

Comment: I think the recommended approach would be to open the port in the firewall, instead of disabling the firewall. `sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=3567 /tcp --permanent`

Comment: Understood, Thanks.